# Reload an array without reloading the page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, instagram

Hey I have a little problem....

Im making a page that uses pictures from instagram as background. To display the pictures i use the jquery plugin [Supersized](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/).

The pictures that i use is from a hashtag, so I would like the page to reload the array, where supersized gets the pictures from, so its updated seamless with the newest pictures.

Its it enough just to reload the array every 5 mins, will the slideshow this work this way or shall I go another way with this?

And can give me a little example on how to do this ?

Comment: I think we need to know what `the array` means.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do then is create an imageQueue array, and a currentImage reference rotating out the current image by what is in the queue. When it is time to update the image queue array I would do it on the off time of rotation. Meaning if your image rotates every 10 seconds it would not make sense to upload the queue every 300 seconds (5 minutes, every 30 images you would end up with a race condition.). Instead I would update the Queue every 307 seconds (prime number)

This should give you a smooth transition and accomplish the goal.